# How to copy contract from mainnet to local node without source code?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, hardhat

I'm deploying contract A locally. I got contract A source code from polygonscan. Contract A has the library **IterableMapping** as a dependency, and that library doesn't have its source code verified, so I can't get my hands either on the source code or the ABI of the library.

How can I copy the contract of the library to my local node to deploy contract A?

library contract: https://polygonscan.com/address/0xbcc560d5a26213c05848735d3b30d8a50e8db896#code

Comment: There is an experimental options called decompile bytecode but thats not alwys accurate, so I suggest just checking at an implementation online like: https://github.com/ethereum/dapp-bin/blob/master/library/iterable_mapping.sol

Comment: @JulissaDC the Contract I'm trying to deploy is using a custom implementation of IterableMapping (I know because some names of the methods are specific to the context of this contract). Isn't there a way to copy the contract? Something similar to forking the entire mainnet locally but instead of doing the entire mainnet, forking only this specific library locally.